# Change Header Size of Boostrap Collapse Widget - Yii 2.0

Tags: php, yii, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

Can anyone tell me how I can change the height of my collapse widget header in Yii 2.0.  It's like 40px right now and I want to make it 20px. The container divs that the widget gets rendered with have class `.panel` and `.panel-default` and `.panel-collapse`, but I'm not sure if there is an option that I can set directly in the collapse widget or if I have to override the CSS somehow? Here is the basic code for the widget (the '`options`' setting only works on the body content not the header).

```
echo Collapse::widget([

        'items' => [

                [
                        'label' => $mycollapseheader,
                        'content' => $contentstring,
                        'encode' => false,
                        //'options' => ['style' => 'background:black'],
                        //'contentOptions' => [],
                ],

        ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/blob/master/Collapse.php) of Collapse widget - there are no way to change header width directly.

You have two way to solve the problem - first modify the Widget (take a look at the `TbGridView` widget which has an `headerHtmlOptions`). So you can use something like this:

```
'headerHtmlOptions' => array(
    'style' => 'width:30px;'
)
```

The second way is to change the value of width per Javascript.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bfcm!  I didn't think of the javascript option.  It turns out that it's a matter of overriding the top and bottom padding on the .panel-heading class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( '.panel-heading').each(function(){

   $( this ).css({'padding':'0px 20px 0px 20px'});

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed the header design in the collapse widget like this:

```
<?php   echo Collapse::widget([

        'encodeLabels' => false,
        'items' => [
            // equivalent to the above
            [
                'label' => '<span class="myclass">MyHeader:</span>',
                'content' => $this->render('_mycollapse', ['model' => $model]) ,
                // open its content by default
                //'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'in']
            ],

        ]
    ]);
    ?>
```

be aware the encodeLabels param is usefull if the Header ist **not** set by client. so you can style "myclass" it now in your "style.css"